# IOS Application to send data to a REST API service content-type definition error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nss

I managed to make an application to send data to a rest api service. The content type must be text/html. But whenever i run my app i get a 415 http code response which means not supported type of content. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL new];

NSData *body = nil;

NSString *contentType = @"text/html"; 

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://telesto.zapto.org:81/SMART_EdgeNode/EdgeNode/DataFeeds/3/addMeasurement"]];
NSString *yourString = @"geoX#35#geoY#65";





contentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

body = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *putLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[body length]];



if (nil==finalURL) {

    finalURL = url;
}


NSMutableDictionary* headers = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[headers setValue:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[headers setValue:@"mimeType" forKey:@"Accept"];
[headers setValue:@"no-cache" forKey:@"Cache-Control"];
[headers setValue:@"no-cache" forKey:@"Pragma"];
[headers setValue:@"close" forKey:@"Connection"];






NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];


[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setValue:putLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

self.conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I guess atm there is something wrong with defining the content-type . Any help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found it at last. It was this specific line that was causing the problem and had to do something with the content-type :

```
contentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
```

After removing that i was able to send properly my string to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the server's complaining that it doesn't know how to generate a response with the content type "mimeType".

Your Accept header should be "text/html" or whatever the content type you expect in the response, not "mimeType".

---

**Update**

After reading this again, I notice that you are setting the contentType to `@"text/html"`, then to `@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"`. Which do you need? From the description, you want to sent `text/html`, but that is not what your sending. When you set `contentType` to `@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"`, `text/html` is lost.

Comment: Hmm! Didn't see notice that "fail of me".Had set mimeType there to replace it later but totally forgot. On the other hand i don't know what the type of respose the server generates so have to figure out. I ll reply later your notice helped :)

Comment: Ok i found out that the server returns a response of type text/xml. I replaced @"mimetype" with @"text/xml" but still getting that 415 error.Any ideas?

Comment: Well two things. See about getting rid of `; charset=utf-8` of the Content-Type. Use `application/xml` as the Accept header.